# db2 docker image of Enterprise Server Edition V10.5 FP 7

Tags: db2

How can I get docker image of db2 LUW V10.5 FP7. I found docker image for V11.1 but could not find any on V10.5 FP7.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 10.5 is going out of support in April 2020.

I would suspect that is one consideration why IBM have not provided a 10.5 docker image.

You should probably be considering migrating to 11.1 or 11.5 at this time.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-distributed-end-support-eos-dates